# how to bind property abc of type IList<string> to textbox as a datafield

Tags: c#, .net, list, activereports, datafield

I am working on a report and I have a property of type IList as follows:

```
public IList<string> abc { get; set; }
```

I have populated this list in code, but how can I assign this populated list to textbox's datafield property in order to get list data on report.

Comment: `string.Join(" ", abc)`

Comment: can you please share more information about your report?   Do you actually want to bind the contents of the list to the textbox in one detail or do you want the detail section to iterate over the IList object.    The answers below describe changing the list to a string and setting the textbox value to that string.  however, you can also bind the whole report to that list by using the DataSource property   this.DataSource = this.abc;

Comment: Yes..I do have to bind contents of list to textboxes which are in a detail section. Ex. List will have data like Code:ABC, Value:XYZ(1st item in list) like this list can have n no of items...Then I have 2 textboxes in a details section..I have to bind 'Code' to one textbox and 'Value' to other.

Answer (score 0):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuiler();  
Foreach (string s in abc)  
   sb.AppendLine(s);
Mytextbox.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Make the TextBox multiline
If you don't want lines then sb.Append()

Comment: No. I don't have to set .text property. Since the textbox is in the detail section of report i have assign the data field property of textbox to this list. Ex. Let's say list contains A,B,C and when i set datafield property as list it should show in report as follows:                                            A                                                                                                               B                                                                                                               C

Comment: So on the other answer with textBox.Text = s; you said the problem is last value.  But now you don't have a .text property?   Textbox will not bind to a List.

Comment: Is there any way i can bind list data to textboxes in a detail section of report??

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the IListBinding sample that comes with the installer?  It essentially does what you are trying to accomplish.

you can find it here on your machine.  (ActiveReports 9)

C:\Users\\Documents\ComponentOne Samples\ActiveReports 9\Section Reports\Data\IListBinding

If you are sill having issues, email activereports.support@grapecity.com with ref to this post.

Comment: I didn't found any sample code..I emailed on above id.